# Checking if image exists before executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of image links that I'm getting from reddit, but some image urls are broken. I want to skip over broken image links.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755183/checking-if-an-image-exists-before-adding-it-as-a-background-image) suggested using .width to see if an image exists. I tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript) to wait for image links to load before executing code but it's not working, it's skipping right over my `if(this.width>0)` check.

```
var imgLinksArray = Array.from(imgLinks);
document.getElementById('photoGrid').innerHTML = "";
for (i = 0; i < imgLinks.length; i++) {
  var workingImgLink = imgLinksArray[i]

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.src + " Width: " + this.width);
    for (i = 0; i < imgLinks.length; i++) {
      var workingImgLink = imgLinksArray[i]

      if (this.width > 0) {
        console.log(this.width);
        if (workingImgLink.search("webm") >= 0) {
          document.getElementById('photoGrid').innerHTML += '<video autoplay loop class="box-wrapper"> <source  type="video/webm" src= "' + workingImgLink + '" data-url= "' + workingImgLink + '" class="box" style=background-image:url("' + workingImgLink + '")></video>';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('photoGrid').innerHTML += '<div class="box-wrapper"> <div  data-url= "' + workingImgLink + '" class="box" style=background-image:url("' + workingImgLink + '")></div></div>';

        }
      }
    }

  }
  img.src = workingImgLink;
  var bgImgWidth = img.width;
  var bgImgHeight = img.height;

}
```

I only want to execute the innerHTML code if I know the image exists. Any suggestions about how to go about this?

Comment: You shouldn't use the inner loop. You are only concerned with the image instance inside the load event handler

Comment: @charlietfl i took out the loop and change my instances of "workingImgLink" to "this.src" and that seems to have worked. thank you. is there a way to give you points for your help?

Comment: I think the problem is the same as :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @charlietfl is there away to award you the bounty?

Comment: You understand the issue now? No worries about the bounty